# Using Multiple SSL Cert on one Google Cloud Instance

Tags: apache, ssl, https, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Okay so I have multiple domains on one GCE Apache Web Server `example1.com`,`example2.com`, and `example3.com`.  Each Domain has there own SSL certificate created and on the web server.  I'm trying to figure out how I can do this.

So far I have tried Virtual Hosting by IPs followed here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding/.
I used static IPs for the forwarding rules, but this solution didn't seem to work.

I then tried HTTPS load balancing the static IPs attaching the ssl certs to the load balancer with the sessions between the load balancer being https as well. I used the docs here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/

This isn't working either and I receive an error like this 
    Error: Server Error

`The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.`

I would appreciate any help that can be given.  Its been a bit frustrating not knowing what is wrong with the setup.  I wish there was a step by step guide out there because I don't think I am the only person doing something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you webserver is properly setup to handle multiple SSL certs on the same interface (SNI), you could just allocate an external IP to the instance and serve it from there.

Comment: I had done this already when I tried Virtual Hosting with the Elastic IPs, I could only get one ssl working.